# iwconfig - Can't Configure Wireless Network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, slackware

I've beenhaving some trouble getting my wireless network card working on my Slackware 12 box.  Currently it identifies the card and can scan for networks, but I can't seem to join a network.  Here's some output:

```
{8:46:29}gibson:/lib/modules/2.6.33.4-smp## iwlist wlan0 scan                  
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: F8:1E:DF:FF:DA:39
                    ESSID:"MasterControl"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                    Mode:Managed
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality:100/100  Signal level:-22 dBm  Noise level:-96 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                              48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Extra:bcn_int=100
                    Extra:atim=0
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: FA:1E:DF:FF:DA:39
                    ESSID:"David's Guest Network"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11g
                    Mode:Managed
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality:100/100  Signal level:-23 dBm  Noise level:-96 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                              48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Extra:bcn_int=100
                    Extra:atim=0
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

{8:49:23}gibson:/lib/modules/2.6.33.4-smp## iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm   
          RTS thr:2347 B   Fragment thr:2346 B   
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

{8:49:48}gibson:/lib/modules/2.6.33.4-smp## iwconfig wlan0 essid "MasterControl"
{8:50:02}gibson:/lib/modules/2.6.33.4-smp## iwconfig wlan0 key s:thisisafakepassword
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
{8:50:17}gibson:/lib/modules/2.6.33.4-smp## iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm   
          RTS thr:2347 B   Fragment thr:2346 B   
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

It doesn't seem to be accepting the `essid` setting, and it's giving an error for the `key` setting.

Also, I'm noticing an inconsistency in the wireless protocols.  The AP claims that it's 802.11g with rates up to 54 Mb/s.  But it *should* be 802.11n.  It's an Apple Airport Extreme and the Radio Mode is set to Automatic and displays "802.11a/n - 802.11b/g/n" on the Airport Utility.  The interface also claims that it's 802.11g, though shows a rate of 300 Mb/s.  It's a Belkin "Play" Wireless USB Adapter (F7D4101).

(Note: I'm using ndiswrapper and the WinXP drivers which were installed from the Belkin software.)

Can anybody advise me on this?  Am I just missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using anything more secure that WEP (which you are) you will have to use `wpa_supplicant` to handle the encryption.

I'm not sure how slakware handles its network configuration these days (I haven't used slakware since version 1.3) but reading the man page for `wpa_supplicant` and associated network configuration man pages should give you some clues.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  It took a little fiddling with the settings in `wpa_supplicant.conf` but the connection is now tested and working (and even transmitting at a proper throughput, from what I can tell so far).